# Default value when getting extra from an AlarmManger started service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am scheduling an alarm manager like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Locale.class);
            intent.putExtra("end",AlarmEnd.getTimeInMillis());

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmStart.getTimeInMillis(), 40 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

So that's working... the problem is when it starts Locale

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int t = START_STICKY;
        SharedPreferences alarms = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("alarms", 0);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        endTime = intent.getLongExtra("end",0);
        Log.d("Alarms", "End time is".concat(endTime.toString()));
```

The debug message always outputs the default value "End time is0".. I know that the extra on the intent is not zero (checked it). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_WAKEUP` alarms are not reliable when used directly with a service. Please use them with a `BroadcastReceiver`, either paired with my `WakefulIntentService` or your own `IntentService`/`WakeLock` combination. With respect to your problem, try `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems to be working pretty reliably.. However I'll definitely consider it.. Changing to UPDATE_CURRENT had no effect.

Comment: "Seems to be working pretty reliably" -- it'll fail occasionally, as the device falls back asleep before the service gets a chance to run, let alone acquire a `WakeLock`.

Comment: I attempted to switch to broadcast receiver... However It could not then register a wifi scan receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved

```
Intent **myIntent** = new Intent(context, Locale.class);
            **intent**.putExtra("end",AlarmEnd.getTimeInMillis());
```

Issue was naming of the intent which I mistakenly set intent extras not "myIntent" extras. Silly me.